# Reading related data between models, which dosn't have navigation properties in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am pretty new to MVC, and i am having problems reading related data between two models, which dosn't have navigation properties.
I've checked out the following topic, but without any luck:
[MVC4 how to load related data without Navigation Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616624/mvc4-how-to-load-related-data-without-navigation-properties)

Here is a link to some pictures of my project:
http://s1067.photobucket.com/user/TimRH/slideshow/

What am i missing or doing wrong? My result is comming back empty

I hope someone can help me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one to many relationship between tables

https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Main Table

```
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MAINTABLENAMEID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CHILDTABLE> ALIAS { get; set; }
```

Child Table (adding navigation property)

```
    [ForeignKey("ALIAS")]
    public int [MAINTABLENAMEID] { get; set; }

    public virtual [MAINTABLE] ALIAS { get; set; }
```

If you do not have the rights to change the DB

You can test the query in SMSS if it works

```
using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    string Query = @"SELECT  C.KritWert ,C.ArtNr,C.DLNr,C.SA
        ,C.Reserviert,C.GenArtNr,C.LKZ,C.LfdNr,C.SortNr,C.KritNr
        ,C.Exclude,C.AnzSofort,C.pk,k.KritWert,k.Amount,k.Brand
        ,k.Model,k.Type_Description
    FROM C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation C
        JOIN Ktype K
            ON Convert(int,C.KritWert) = k.KritWert");

   ObjectQuery<[NEWMODEL]> query = new ObjectQuery<[NEWMODEL]>
                               (Query,db, MergeOption.NoTracking);
}
```

Comment: Then i get this error: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<CrossTest_V2.Models.Ktype>' does not contain a definition for 'Brand' and no extension method 'Brand' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<CrossTest_V2.Models.Ktype>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Users\trh\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\CrossTest_V2\CrossTest_V2\Views\Home\Index.cshtml 161 70 CrossTest_V2
But Brand is in Ktype

Comment: Can you post the 2 models (classes) please + the code from the identiymodel with the 2 two classes in it ( public DbSet<MAINTABLE> MAINALIAS { get; set; }   public DbSet<CHILDTABLE> CHILDALIAS { get; set; }  )

Comment: Sure, i'll post it in a new answer

Comment: you are matching a int (FK) to a string(PK) that is not possible, change them booth to 1 matching datatype (int)

Comment: But they are like this in the database, one is a string, the other is a int. Is there a way around this? I know this i bad, but this is how it is. (Database from external source)

Comment: In that case you cannot create one to many relation (on a database level). But you can match them in your query (you need to convert one to the other, so they match up)

Comment: My query? Could you explain this :) Sorry for for my poor experience

Comment: To make the best of the situation you could consider the following options:  Whitin Linq / lambda  use StringCompare => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w(v=vs.110).aspx or you could write the a "normal" query ==> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738694(v=vs.100).aspx and in this query you can use cast or convert to match your int and string. I will add a suggestion to my main answer.

Answer (score 0):

Main model:

```
    namespace CrossTest_V2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation
    {
        public string ArtNr { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> DLNr { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SA { get; set; }
        public string Reserviert { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> GenArtNr { get; set; }
        public string LKZ { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LfdNr { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> SortNr { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> KritNr { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public string KritWert { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Exclude { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> AnzSofort { get; set; }
        public int pk { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Ktype> Ktype { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Child model:

```
namespace CrossTest_V2.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

    public partial class Ktype
    {
        [ForeignKey("KritWert")]
        public int KritWert { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Amount { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public string Model { get; set; }
        public string Type_Description { get; set; }

        public virtual C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation C400Ktype { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
using CrossTest_V2.Models;

namespace CrossTest_V2.ViewModels
{
    public class CrossViewModel : DbContext
    {
        public List<Cross> Crosses { get; set; }
        public List<C203_Reference_Numbers> Refnr { get; set; }
        public List<C203_Reference_Numbers> Refnr2 { get; set; }
        public List<C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation> C400 { get; set; }
        public List<C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation> C400_2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
 TCDEntities db = new TCDEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        CrossViewModel vm = new CrossViewModel();

        vm.Crosses = db.Crosses.Take(1).ToList();

        Cross cross = db.Crosses.FirstOrDefault();

        // List<C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation> C400 = db.C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation.Where(k => k.ArtNr == cross.Article_From && k.DLNr == cross.Supplier_From && k.KritNr == 2).ToList();

        vm.Refnr = db.C203_Reference_Numbers.Where(r => r.ArtNr == cross.Article_From && r.DLNr == cross.Supplier_From).ToList();
        vm.Refnr2 = db.C203_Reference_Numbers.Where(r => r.ArtNr == cross.Article_To && r.DLNr == cross.Supplier_To).ToList();

        // C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation article = db.C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation.Where(k => k.ArtNr == cross.Article_From && k.DLNr == cross.Supplier_From && k.KritNr == 2);

        vm.C400 = db.C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation.Where(k => k.ArtNr == cross.Article_From && k.DLNr == cross.Supplier_From && k.KritNr == 2).ToList();
        vm.C400_2 = db.C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation.Where(k => k.ArtNr == cross.Article_To && k.DLNr == cross.Supplier_To && k.KritNr == 2).ToList();

        //var C400Ktype = db.C400_Article_Search_Tree_Allocation.Where(k => k.ArtNr == cross.Article_From && k.DLNr == cross.Supplier_From && k.KritNr == 2).ToList();

        return View(vm);
    }
```